# Is it possible to ensure that a local server is not accessible from the outside?

Tags: networking, apache-http-server

I want to setup a local server (Apache 2.4) on a computer that's located in my workplace.

I want it to be accessible from all the computers in the local network but not accessible from the outside. I want it to be 100% bulletproof. 0% chance that a hacker can access it and then get access to our local network.

Is that possible? I've tried to use port 8888 and our firewall doesn't port forward that port. Is that enough? Or are there other safety measures you would have to take? Or is it even possible?

Comment: Using a port that is not forwarded is enough. Malicious actor must be in your local network already if it's not enough. You can test it yourself from the outside network. Usually in home networks any access to services is denied by default, so you must do additional configuration to allow access to those services from the internet.

Comment: As pointed out, this is indeed enough, but it is never bulletproof. If a hacker can find a way inside the network, they will always be able to get to your server. But the chances of that happening is 1%.

Comment: I think you have the scenario the wrong way round. More likely that an attacker will get access to your local network _first,_ e.g. through an infected PC, and only then start looking at what webservers and other services are available internally.

Comment: Add basic auth to your local web server. Sure, an intruder would be able to scan for your web server’s existence, but with basic auth they could not get into the site itself.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to ***100%*** prevent outside access to a network is to physcially disconnect it from the internet. If its connected to a network with internet access, there will *always* be the possibility of external access due to human error, software error, or hardware error.

Obviously, that is not a real world option.  However, there are best practices on securing and limiting access to and from computers, networks, and servers.

As [@user168 said in his comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1749979/is-it-possible-to-ensure-that-a-local-server-is-not-accessible-from-the-outside#comment2715920_1749979), it is the user's computers that are most likely to be the point of entry.  If they are connected to the internet and get infected by malware, then your internal network has been compromised.